How to run an asynchronous function in flask?
My code:
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook():
    data = request.form.to_dict()
    if 'event' in data and data['event'] == 'ONTASKCOMMENTADD':
        task_id = data['data[FIELDS_AFTER][TASK_ID]']
        com_id = data['data[FIELDS_AFTER][ID]']
        url = url_crm + "task.commentitem.get"
        headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
        headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        data = {"TASKID":task_id,"ITEMID":com_id}
#        try:
        maker_id = get_bitrix24_tgid(get_bitrix24_task(task_id)['RESPONSIBLE_ID'])
        resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data).json()['result']
        files = []
        if 'ATTACHED_OBJECTS' in resp:
            for key in resp['ATTACHED_OBJECTS']:
                files.append(get_link(resp['ATTACHED_OBJECTS'][key]['FILE_ID']))
        asyncio.create_task(notify_user(resp['AUTHOR_NAME'], maker_id, task_id, resp['POST_MESSAGE'], files))
#        except:
#            pass
    return jsonify({'status': 'ok'})

async def notify_user(author, user_id, task_id, text, links):
    print(author, user_id, task_id, text, links)
    if len(links) == 0:
        task = get_bitrix24_task(task_id)
        print(task)
        if task != 'Error':
            keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            if int(task['REAL_STATUS']) <= 2:
                start_data = 'start_' + task_id 
                start_btn = InlineKeyboardButton(text='starts', callback_data=start_data)
                keyboard.add(start_btn)
            elif task['REAL_STATUS'] == '3':
                stop_data = 'stop_' + task_id 
                stop_btn = InlineKeyboardButton(text='stopp', callback_data=stop_data)
                keyboard.add(stop_btn)
            com_data = 'com_' + task_id 
            com_btn = InlineKeyboardButton(text='comm', callback_data=com_data)
            keyboard.add(com_btn)
            temp_txt = '111'
            await bot.send_message(int(user_id), temp_txt)

I need to run an asynchronous function from the usual one to send a message to telegram, after notifying the server.
I tried create_task, got the error:

Tracking (last call last): File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py ", line 1473, in
wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py ", line 882, in
full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py ", line 880, in
full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py ", line 865, in
dispatch_request returns
self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args) #
type: ignore[no return]  File "/home/bot/main.py ", line 326, in the
webhook asyncio.create_task(user
notification_(respectively['AUTHOR_NAME'], creator ID, task id_,
respectively['POST_MESSAGE'], files))

When using asyncio.run, I get an error at the moment when the bot sends a message to the telegram:

RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task.

I ask for help, please

Using async and await

After installing flask[async] and adding await and asynchronous receipt of RuntimeError: the context manager timeout should be used inside the task
